# dice roll (first time), program through nested for loops

Tags: python, numpy, random

I tried to write a code to **roll dice**, code ends if the number is *less than 6*. But it continues if 6 comes, then continues if 6 comes then terminates if 6 comes or any other number(< 6) comes. But rather I get

```
6 again
6 again
6 again
```

like that, if 6 comes initially.

I am weak at nested loops and new at Python. The code is,

```
dice = np.random.randint(1,7)

i = 1

for i in range(1):
    if (dice == 6):
        print(dice, 'again')
        continue
        for i in range(1):
            if (dice == 6):
                print(dice, 'again')
                continue
                for i in range(1):
                    if (dice == 6):
                        print(dice, 'break')
                    else:
                        print(dice, 'over')
            else:
                print(dice, 'over')
            i+=1
    else:
        print(dice, 'over')
        break
```

I have few questions related to it:

1. Issue is with `range`, how to tackle it?
2. Can we use nested for loops after `continue`?
3. Where to write I iteration?

Comment: Your random number generation is happening at the beginning of the code, outside of the loop, that means it only happens once, so your dice will forever be the value generated the first run. Second thing is your for loop range, if range is 1, your loop will only run one iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want a `for` loop?

Use a `while` loop:

This one will repeat for 3 times.

```
import numpy as np
counter = 1
while True:
    dice = np.random.randint(1,7)
    if counter==3:
        print(dice,"break")
        break
    elif dice==6:
        print(dice,"again!")
        counter+=1
    else:
        print('Over!')
        break
```

The following will do it until 6 comes

```
import numpy as np
while True:
    dice = np.random.randint(1,7)
    if dice!=6:
        print(dice,"again!")
    else:
        print('Over!')
        break
```